# Updating a custom table from the AspNetUser table on registration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Im new to MVC. So please be kind if I am doing something against best practices, or I am just completely wrong all together.
Im using ASP.Net MVC 5 in C#
I started off by using a code first approach with EF. After setting up my models in a separate project, and enabled migrations, created my database with the standard tables used the Identities framework and some custom tables.

Here is where I’m having the problem.  When a new user registers an account, the AspNetUser table is populated, now I want to update a column in a UserInfo table with the AspNetUserId. 
I tried using data annotations to set it as a foreign key, but the UserInfo table wouldn’t update with the AspNetUserId when a new user registered an account. I assume Im not using the annotations correctly. Either way. What is the best way to achieve the results Im looking for?

Coded examples would really help.

Here is the custom model.

```
public class UserInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]

    public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

}
```

Im not sure what else, if anything, to show. If im missing something, let me know and Ill post what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an one-to-one map between your `UserInfo` entity and Identity's `ApplicationUser` simply alter your classes like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    // other codes here

    public string UserID {get;set;}
    public virtual ApplicationUser User {get;set;}    
}

public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // other properties

    public int InfoID {get;set;}
    public virtual UserInfo Info {get;set;}
}
```